# Avoid linebreak before cite

Tags: citing, line-breaking

I often find myself typing

```
... see~\cite{reference}.
```

because I don't  want my new lines to start with citations (I think it looks really bad).

But of course always inserting a `~` is a bit tedious, because my fingers tend to gravity more towards the `space` key than the `~` key.

Is there any way to force LaTeX to interpret `see \cite{ref}` internally as `see~\cite{ref}`?

BTW: I don't care about line breaks within citations, I think they are fine.

Answer (score 7):

If you are sure that *none* of your cite commands start a paragraph, e.g not

```
  text text.

  \cite{X} has shown ...
```

then you can do this with a simple command hook (available since 2021/06/01 in LaTeX). All you then need is a single line in the preamble and it even works if after that the cite command changes (e.g., when later a package modifies it):

```
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{cmd/cite/before}{\unskip~}  % <-- only that is needed

\ShowCommand\cite

\usepackage{natbib}

\ShowCommand\cite

\showoutput

\begin{document}

\ShowCommand\cite

A \cite{X}

\end{document}
```

The `\ShowCommand`s are only to see what the definition looks like at different points in the document.

### Update

As suggested by David one could also easily handle the case that the cites starts out in vertical mode by using

```
\AddToHook{cmd/cite/before}{\ifhmode\unskip~\fi}
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

How about defining a macro

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{~\cite{#1}}
```

and then citing via something like this?

```
see\mycite{ref}
```

Comment: Haha, cheers :D Well, it doesn't quite answer the question, because I still have to change my typing-behavior. So I need to ponder whether I can accept this as an answer.

Comment: Another possibility is to write a shell script to replace each occurrence of " \cite" with "~\cite" and set up your compiler to run the shell script before latexing the tex file.

Comment: Good point. I'm using vimtex, might try to write a vimscript function that gets called before compilation.

Comment: @JoMo you could use `\ifhmode\unskip\fi~`  in the defintion then you could put an ignored space before `\mycite`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in thnat case better have the `~` also inside the conditional. That could, of course, also be applied to my approach.